Can't remove the liquidity from uniswap
I deployed a contract on the blockchain that had no buy and sell function (mistake). This contract is verified by Etherscan, and I've added 0.8 ETH of liquidity that I can't withdraw because the contract's functions don't allow me to. What can I do from here to recover my liquidity from Uniswap?
Contract address: 0x17F4FC23902356e3cC70B9244310F84733F24701
Thanks in advance for your answer.
If you can resolve, I will send you some eth immediately

I don't know what you mean by buy/sell function, tokens don't need that. They just need to be able to be transferred without some mechanic in the token blocking that.
I have seen a lot of people permanently lock their eth in v2, especially if copy some meme that has tax or router address hardcoded.
Pool is failing when it tries to transfer your token, and your token tries to make a tax transfer.
If I use a fork to first approve the router, and then call remove, it fails at _applyTax
IERC20(recipient).safeTransfer(recipient, taxAmount); // Transfer taxes to the recipient
Looks like you do apply tax on every transfer and I don't see any admin functions to change that.
Your token finally fails with:
"[ERROR]":"AddressEmptyCode["0x727f8beee489d96c676095792513a3f3a9fd79f5"]"
As requirement of functionCall is target must be a contract, and your wallet address has no code there:
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - `target` must be a contract.
     * - calling `target` with `data` must not revert.
     */
    function functionCall(address target, bytes memory data) internal returns (bytes memory) {
        return functionCallWithValue(target, data, 0);
    }

At point of _callOptionalReturn your address is being passed as the token to transfer.
"[FUNCTION]":"functionCallWithValue"
"[OPCODE]":"JUMP"
"contract":{
"address":"0x17f4fc23902356e3cc70b9244310f84733f24701"
}
"caller":{
"address":"0x487310e748bfb81c7c5906241cfccc8dfc37e649"
"balance":"0"
}
"input":{
"target":"0x727f8beee489d96c676095792513a3f3a9fd79f5"
"data":"0xa9059cbb000000000000000000000000727f8beee489d96c676095792513a3f3a9fd79f50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
"value":"0"

I'm not sure there is a way, but it's worth maybe trying to simulate deploying a contract that is set up to make the removal, following the requirements listed in the functions being called in your contract:
- the calling contract must have an ETH balance of at least `value`.
- the called Solidity function must be `payable`.
- `target` must be a contract.
- calling `target` with `data` must not revert.

etc. You might find other issues after, if you can resolve those.
Think it is worth trying to explore as there might be some way. It's not a hardcoded incorrect router address for example.
Maybe I missed something obvious and it is just guaranteed stuck, but it will take a fair few sims to even test.
Would need to deploy the contract, send it the lp, try the removal etc,
If simmed needs a fork so you can do the sequential transactions one after the other, or a "traceCallMany"  across them.
Could try: https://tenderly.co, to set up forks and simulations.
Careful of people who claim they can rescue it, I think it's worth looking but don't get any false hope as it's probably gone.
On a personal level, don't commit your money without proper testing in future, without understanding how the components of your contract fit together.
Good luck, will look deeper if can get a chance.
